# Multiple meta-regression with metafor

Tags: r, metafor

I have performed a multiple meta-regression with the package metafor, but struggle with the interpretation of the *Test of Moderators* (i.e., QM). My model includes two variables: (1) sample type (dummy: community vs. forensic) and (2) proportion of females in sample (continuous).

This is the output I get:

[image]

The results indicate that *proportion_females* is significantly predicting the effect size while controlling for *sample type*. However, QM shows a non-significant result (p < 0.05).

How is that possible? It was my understanding that QM tests the hypothesis H0: β_sample = β_females = 0. If *Proportion_females* is clearly != 0, why does QM not yield a significant result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen just like in regular regression (where the overall/omnibus F-test can fail to be significant, but an individual coefficient is found to be significant). This is more likely to happen when the model includes multiple non-relevant predictors/moderators, since this will decrease the power of the omnibus test. It can also go the other way around where none of the individual coefficients are found to be significant, but the omnibus test is.

Comment: Thank you! Am I still able to draw any conclusions from this then?

Comment: That depends on what strategy you had to begin with. Some will only look at individual coefficients if the omnibus test is significant. Others will interpret individual coefficients regardless of the significance of the omnibus test. Some will consider p = .0647 'marginally significant', others will frown upon this and will then say that p = .0387 therefore must be 'marginally insignificant'. In the end, nobody can tell you what conclusions you should draw from these results and you will have to make up your own mind.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much for your help!